# Litespeed Cache Plugin Conflicts Issue with Youtube Videos

Tags: wordpress, caching, litespeed

There seems to be a conflict with Litespeed Cache and Youtube videos. My embedded Youtube videos can be seen if viewed from my laptop, but not on mobile devices.

I have checked with Site Origin Page Builder, which I am using, and they cannot find any issues with their plugin.

I have also reconfigured the Litespeed cache plugin according to the recommendations. But the issue remains.

But once I deactivate the Litespeed Cache plugin, the issue is solved and the YT videos show up.

I deactivaed the Litespeed cache plugin and tested it with another caching plugin, such as Hummingbird, and it has no such issue.

Comment: Welcome! Probably best to reach out to the plugin developers support. We have no idea what your settings are.

Comment: This site is for questions about programming

Comment: FYI, here's the place where you can post the LSCache-related questions. https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/litespeed-cache/